# TextBox.Text = floatValue.ToString messes with separator symbol

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

When a float value is assigned to a textBox.Text via `floatVal.ToString()` method, it makes local culture separator a `,` How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do you just want to specify your own format? `floatVal.ToString("0.00")` ?

Comment: Format is different each time. Problem is the decimal point becomes a comma and my existing methods then convert the float number to something completely unwanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` solves this problem at least in my case.